# ROC curve issue for multiple users

Tags: machine-learning, classification, error, roc

I have a system that has a classifier and multiple users. To test each user I train a binary classifier for each genuine user and all other users. I find that the score scales seem to be different. This means that some scores are lower than others for different users. This means that EERs and ROC curves for testing on a whole dataset appears worse than for each user, but it's not feasible to show an ROC curve for each user. The image below displays this. The purple lines show the EERs for individual users and will be 0, but the orange line shows the EER for the whole dataset which means that half of the dataset (for these 2 users) is falsely accepted and the other half falsely rejected. Is there a protocol or technique to deal with this? Most studies seem to generate an ROC curve over the whole dataset but isn't this an issue?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you simply show the AUC values for all users on a box plot?

Comment: I don't get what you're doing, but this sounds a bit like multi-reader ROC curve analysis to me. See for instance http://pubs.rsna.org/doi/abs/10.1148/radiol.2432060387 ...